# Counting nested sets children

Tags: sql, nested-sets

I have created the following fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc0d9/19

I am trying to count the number of immediate children each node has by adapting the SQL from the following:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

```
CREATE TABLE Personnel 
    (
     name varchar(20), 
     lft int,
     rgt int
    );

SELECT Parent.name, count(Child.*)
FROM Personnel AS Child, Personnel AS Parent 
WHERE Parent.lft < Child.lft AND Parent.rgt > Child.rgt
GROUP BY Parent.name
```

Comment: Is this the right data? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc0d9/20

Comment: Yes, it's the Personnel data. My SQL show the count of all descendants however I am seeking to limit the count to immediate children. The wikipedia link shows how to return only the immediate children however I can't figure out how to count them.

Answer (score 3):

The following fixes your syntax error:

```
SELECT Parent.name, count(*)
FROM Personnel AS Child join
     Personnel AS Parent 
     on Parent.lft < Child.lft AND Parent.rgt > Child.rgt  -- associate Child Nodes with ancestors
GROUP BY Parent.name;
```

SQL does not permit the expression `count(child.*)`.